# jQuery .val Cyrillic Values Passed to PayPal Form Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, paypal, cyrillic

Following is a simplified version of a feature I'm working on. If someone can help with this, I can easily adapt it to my real world situation.

In my example, if the form is submitted with the English version of input[id=item_name] active in the JavaScript, it works. With the Russian version of input[id=item_name] active, it doesn't work...the problem is that when you end up on PayPal, the description is Gobbledygook.

If you submit the form with each version of input[id=item_name] active you will see the problem when you get to PayPal (on the Description).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@website.com">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="RU">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="">
<input type="hidden"name="amount" id="amount" value="">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">


/*This Doesn't Work*/
$('input[id=item_name]').val('50 слов перевода');

/*This Does Work*/
/*$('input[id=item_name]').val('50 Word Translation');*/


$('input[id=amount]').val('5.00');      
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add an extra input field to your form and see if it changes anything?

```
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
```

Check this as well: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/19293/paypal-greek-characters.aspx#84782
I don't have access to a PP Sandbox at the moment, otherwise I'd attempt to help more.

Comment: That absolutely worked, thank you. Sometimes you just stare at something for too long. Thank you, thank you :)